# Compile ERROR: The type is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, linq, .net-assembly, 3-tier

I'm working on a 3-tier application. I added a Linq to SQL table (LEAVE) using the O/R Designer. I added the method below for retrieving data from the table (LEAVE) in a class (LeaveRecord) in the Business Layer.

```
public IQueryable<LEAVE> getLeaves()
{
    dbContext db = new dbContext;
    return db.LEAVEs;
}
```

On the UI layer, in the code behind for the webform, I tried to get the data like this:

```
bll.LeaveRecord leaveRecords = new bll.LeaveRecord();
var data = leaveRecords.getLeaves(); // the error message highlights this line (41) as the offender
```

When I run the program, I get a compilation error:

```
The type 'programname.dal.LEAVE' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'programname.dal, version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' (Line 41).
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most simple solution is add reference to dal from the UI project.

Comment: Thanks Iswanto. Any code example on how to do that?
Thanks.

Comment: I tried "Using projectname.dal;", but I get the error that the type or namespace 'dal' doesn't exist in the namespace 'projectname'.

Comment: have you add reference to dal from ui project? In your solution explorer, go to ui project, right click on reference, choose project -> dal.

Answer (score 2):

You are exposing `dal` data types from your `bll`.  Thus if anyone wants to consume that the `bll` API (i.e. your UI) would need to also reference the `dal`.

So you have the choice of referencing your `dal` from your `UI` or doing a data type switch in the `bll` and exposing new data type that is defined in the `bll`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm fairly new to ASP.NET. Please can you show me a little code example. Thank you.

Comment: This is an architectural decision.  The only code that applies is do you want a new data type in your bll or do you want callers of the bll to have to reference the dal.

Comment: I don't know the consequences of either decision. You are in a better position to suggest for me which one to use and how to do it. I just want it to work.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You have to marshal your data objects:

```
public DaoLeave
{
    // Properties of DaoLeave, same as properties of LEAVE

    internal void DaoLeave(LEAVE doLeave)
    {
        // set properties from properties ... alternately, use something like AutoMapper
    }
}

public IQueryable<DaoLeave> getLeaves()
{
    dbContext db = new dbContext;
    return db.LEAVEs.Select(l => new DaoLeave(l));
}
```